# NUXT - Folder structure for dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need this type of route:

```
www.mywebsite.com/[category_#]/[product_#]
```

The folder structure that makes this work is:

```
/pages
  /_id
    /_id
      index.vue
    index.vue    
index.vue
```

Needless to say, that is very confusing. And I would imagine I am doing something wrong here. How can I build the desired route structure while also being clear in the actual names of the files/folders?

EDIT: I am also open to 'better' folder structures should you have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `_id`, you could use `_category` and `_product`:

```
/pages
  /_category
    _product.vue
```

Then in `/pages/_category/_product.vue`, you could access the slugs through the route's `params`:

```js
export default {
  async asyncData({ params }) {
    console.log(params.category, params.product)
  }
}
```